# How can I use an equation and if statement inside of a variable? It's not working

Tags: android, kotlin, if-statement, variables, equation

So I'm printing my variable recommendedCalories and I gave it a standard input of 0 to see if anything was being printed, and so it prints 0. But with the values of the variables I got from a previous screen I should get a different answer. What's going on that my equation isn't getting the answer I want?

```
package com.example.optilife

import...

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)

        val userAge = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_AGE", 0)
        val userHeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", 0)
        val userWeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", 0)
        val userGender = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_GENDER")
        val userActivityLevel = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ACTIVITYLEVEL")
        var userWeightGoal = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHTGOAL")
        var userWeightGoalCalories = {
            userWeightGoal = if (userWeightGoal == "Weight loss") {
                "300"
            } else if (userWeightGoal == "Maintain weight") {
                "0"
            } else {
                "-300"
            }
        }

        var recommendedCalories = 0
        var recommendedCaloriesCalculator = {
            recommendedCalories = if (userGender == "Male") {
                (66 + 13.7userWeight + 5userHeight - 6.8userAge -                     
userWeightGoal.toString().toInt()).toString().toInt()
            } else {
                (655 + 9.6userWeight + 1.8userHeight - 4.7userAge -    
userWeightGoal.toString().toInt()).toString().toInt()
            }
    }

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_Test).apply {
            text = recommendedCalories.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have created a function `recommendedCaloriesCalculator()` here:

```kotlin
var recommendedCaloriesCalculator = {
    recommendedCalories = ...
}
```

So if you do not explicitly call `recommendedCaloriesCalculator()`, `recommendedCalories = ...` will never be executed and therefore `recommendedCalories` is not updated.

So you can:

1. Call `recommendedCaloriesCalculator()` before setting the TextView
2. Simply remove `var recommendedCaloriesCalculator = { ... }` and leave `recommendedCalories = ...` there

Option 1:

```kotlin
package com.example.optilife

import...

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)

        val userAge = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_AGE", 0)
        val userHeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", 0)
        val userWeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", 0)
        val userGender = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_GENDER")
        val userActivityLevel = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ACTIVITYLEVEL")
        var userWeightGoal = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHTGOAL")
        var userWeightGoalCalories = {
            userWeightGoal = if (userWeightGoal == "Weight loss") {
                "300"
            } else if (userWeightGoal == "Maintain weight") {
                "0"
            } else {
                "-300"
            }
        }

        var recommendedCalories = 0
        // BTW, are you missing * for the following equations?
        var recommendedCaloriesCalculator = {
            recommendedCalories = if (userGender == "Male") {
                (66 + 13.7userWeight + 5userHeight - 6.8userAge -                     
userWeightGoal.toString().toInt()).toString().toInt()
            } else {
                (655 + 9.6userWeight + 1.8userHeight - 4.7userAge -    
userWeightGoal.toString().toInt()).toString().toInt()
            }
        }
        // Call the function here to update recommendedCalories
        recommendedCaloriesCalculator()
        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_Test).apply {
            text = recommendedCalories.toString()
        }
    }
}
```

Option 2:

```kotlin
package com.example.optilife

import...

class WelcomeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome)

        val userAge = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_AGE", 0)
        val userHeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_HEIGHT", 0)
        val userWeight = intent.getIntExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHT", 0)
        val userGender = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_GENDER")
        val userActivityLevel = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_ACTIVITYLEVEL")
        var userWeightGoal = intent.getStringExtra("EXTRA_WEIGHTGOAL")
        var userWeightGoalCalories = {
            userWeightGoal = if (userWeightGoal == "Weight loss") {
                "300"
            } else if (userWeightGoal == "Maintain weight") {
                "0"
            } else {
                "-300"
            }
        }

        var recommendedCalories = 0
        // The simplest solution is to remove recommendedCaloriesCalculator
        // BTW, are you missing * for the following equations?
        recommendedCalories = if (userGender == "Male") {
            (66 + 13.7userWeight + 5userHeight - 6.8userAge - userWeightGoal.toString().toInt()).toString().toInt()
        } else {
            (655 + 9.6userWeight + 1.8userHeight - 4.7userAge - userWeightGoal.toString().toInt()).toString().toInt()
        }

        findViewById<TextView>(R.id.tv_Test).apply {
            text = recommendedCalories.toString()
        }
    }
}
```